# How to fit a pandas timeseries to a 24h graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas timeseries of multiple months and want to count occurences of a feature for different times of day.

I.e. I want to create a graph (using seaborn or matplotlib) with the time of day on the x axis (0 to 24 hours) and the relative number of occurences of a column on the y axis [(like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvZ2c.png).

I can't figure out how to format the timeseries correctly to make this work.

**Edit**:

[image]

This is a sample of the data I'm dealing with. "Open Data Channel Type" can assume five kinds (Online, Phone, Mobile, Unknown, Other). My goal is to plot every kind into one graph, displaying which kind occurs at which time of day.

Comment: You should provide some sample data to let us better understand what you are dealing with

Comment: Added a sample of the data, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare the plot data first:

```
hour = df['Created Date'].dt.hour.rename('Hour')
df_plot = df.groupby(hour).apply(lambda x: x['Open Data Channel Type'].value_counts() / x.shape[0]) \
            .rename_axis(index=['Hour', 'Channel Type']) \
            .to_frame('Frequency') \
            .reset_index()
```

A sample of `df_plot`:

```
   Hour Channel Type  Frequency
0     0        OTHER   0.223744
1     0        PHONE   0.210046
2     0       MOBILE   0.205479
3     0      UNKNOWN   0.198630
4     0       ONLINE   0.162100
5     1      UNKNOWN   0.206311
6     1        OTHER   0.203883
7     1        PHONE   0.201456
8     1       MOBILE   0.196602
9     1       ONLINE   0.191748
```

Then you can make the plot (here using Seaborn):

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_plot, x='Hour', y='Frequency', hue='Channel Type')
ax.figure.set_size_inches(10, 4)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Result (using random data):

[image: Relative frequency plot]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly I get "NameError: name 'hour' is not defined" when I try to execute this command. I tried dt.hour but it does not work either.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Updated my answer